# ListBox Control hidden, not showing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've started transforming my project from its current unstable nature to a more efficient MVVM model,
since doing so, my ListBoxes created in my view areas aren't rendering anymore. The code build & runs smoothly, 
but the listbox control stays empty ..
This happens once I call the method fillList from a different class

```
public void FillList(List<StockItem> sList)
{
    List<StockItem> locallist = new List<StockItem>();

    locallist.Add(new StockItem { AvailableStock = " ijeifji", BlockedStock = "ijji", DetailedInfo = "rrkorkork", IDCode = "rokro", TotalStock = " iijerijer", UOM = "o", WarehouseName = "blargh" });
    locallist.Add(new StockItem { AvailableStock = " ijeifji", BlockedStock = "ijji", DetailedInfo = "rrkorkork", IDCode = "rokro", TotalStock = " iijerijer", UOM = "o", WarehouseName = "blargh" });
    locallist.Add(new StockItem { AvailableStock = " ijeifji", BlockedStock = "ijji", DetailedInfo = "rrkorkork", IDCode = "rokro", TotalStock = " iijerijer", UOM = "o", WarehouseName = "blargh" });

    listBox.ItemsSource = locallist;
   // listBox.ItemsSource = siList;
}
```

In here I've created a TEMPORAL list called locallist to test out my connection offline,
the list sList sent to the method is a similar list, containing items with the same Binding names, just way.. way larger ...

The XAML of my listbox is :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" FontSize="26" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="176" Width="444" Background="#00292828">
                <Grid Height="159" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#6C5A5A5A">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IDCode}" Height="28" Margin="8,7,164,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="17.333"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DetailedInfo}" Margin="8,39,164,0" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="17.333"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="24,73,15,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Text="TOTAL  "/><Run Text=" AVAILABLE  "/><Run Text=" BLOCKED"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,-4" Text="{Binding TotalStock}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="61" Width="97" FontSize="18.667" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Margin="144,0,0,-4" Text="{Binding AvailableStock}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="61" FontSize="18.667" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="102"/>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,40,-4" Text="{Binding BlockedStock}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="61" Width="108" FontSize="18.667" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,0,0,6.733" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UOM}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="13.333"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,172.343,6.733" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UOM}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="13.333"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15.343,6.733" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding UOM}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="13.333"/>
                </Grid>
                <Button Content="Details" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="73" Width="146" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Foreground="#FFAAC028"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Margin="0,-0.167,150.589,0" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="57.75" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6.906">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform SkewX="21.737" TranslateX="19.935"/>
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                </Rectangle>
                <!--<Button Click="Button_Click"/>-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The problem starts when I call upon the FillList method (located in the StockItemOverview.xaml.cs) from my ViewModel.cs (here the list gets created & sent to FillList(List sList)
As soon as the program finishes the FillList method, it continues running, but no listbox appears!
Please help!

EDIT 
Code from my ViewModel.cs

```
public void PopulateListbox(List<StockItem> sentSI, int MAX)
{
    List<StockItem> stockItemList = new List<StockItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        stockItemList.Add(new StockItem() { IDCode = sentSI[i].IDCode, DetailedInfo = sentSI[i].DetailedInfo, AvailableStock = sentSI[i].AvailableStock, BlockedStock = sentSI[i].BlockedStock, TotalStock = sentSI[i].TotalStock, UOM = sentSI[i].UOM });
        //stockItemList.Add(new StockItem() { IDCode = "Hubla", DetailedInfo = "17 C", AvailableStock = "20", BlockedStock = "10", TotalStock = "30" });
    }

    StockItemOverview pageDisplayer = new StockItemOverview();

    pageDisplayer.FillList(stockItemList);
}
```

and the StockItem class :

```
public class StockItem
{
    public string IDCode { get; set; }
    public string AvailableStock { get; set; }
    public string BlockedStock { get; set; }
    public string TotalStock { get; set; }
    public string DetailedInfo { get; set; }
    public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you set datatcontex? does StocItem implement INorifyPropertyChanged? Start a new project in VS with Pivot template. What you have there is a basic example of MVVM.

Comment: What happens if you change your List<StockItem> to ObservableCollection<StockItem>?

Comment: I have problems understanding the DataContext / INotifyPropertyChanged elements since they seem very outdated, replacing Lists with Observable Collections is giving me the same results : 

Empty Listbox

Comment: But THANK YOU for pointing out that the Pivot sample page is actually the perfect example to get information from!

Comment: the Itemtemplate looks wrong I would have a look at those margins

Comment: one question, what does "StockItemOverview pageDisplayer = new StockItemOverview();" statment stand for?? I tried out your code and runs with no problem, except PopulateListbox method...

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts.

1. Create a BaseModel class.
2. a. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged (use the appropriate namespace).
   b. Implement the methods.

example:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
   PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
   if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
}
```

1. All your Model classes (StockItem for example) would inherit from the BaseModel class.
2. Have the get and set spelled out for all the fields of StockItem class. And call the PropertyChanged method by giving the corresponding public property name as parameter, in the Set method.

example:

```
private string _idCode;

public string IDCode
{
 get{
      return _idCode;
    }
 set{
     _idCode = value;
     PropertyChanged("IDCode");
    }
}
```

1. Convert all List<> to ObservableCollection<>
2. Have your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface or inherit from a BaseViewModel (like the BaseModel explained above, which implements the interface). 
   Define the collection also be a property. Call the PropertyChanged method as we did for the Model class.
3. Have listBox.ItemsSource = locallist; statement in the Load event or in your constructor.
4. Set the DataContext propety to the ViewModel.

Comment: The bullet numbers are off. Tried fixing them, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

So after screwing around with the code another day I've noticed I created 2 instances of the ViewModel and calling on eachother's StockList ... By correctly using the same instance of the ViewModel, the listbox now correctly draws,
you do have to change the StockItem class to:

```
public class StockItem
{
        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        //      public string IDCode { get; set; }
        //      public string AvailableStock { get; set; }
        //      public string BlockedStock { get; set; }
        //      public string TotalStock { get; set; }
        //      public string DetailedInfo { get; set; }
        //      public string WarehouseName { get; set; }
        //      public string UOM { get; set; }

        //public StockItem() { }

        // public StockItem(string idcode, string avstock, string blstock, string totstock, string detinfo, string warehouse, string uom) 
        //  {
        //         this.IDCode = idcode;
        //         this.AvailableStock = avstock;
        //         this.BlockedStock = blstock;
        //         this.TotalStock = totstock;
        //         this.DetailedInfo = detinfo;
        //         this.WarehouseName = warehouse;
        //         this.UOM = uom;

        //     }
    private string _idcode;

    public string IDCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _idcode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _idcode)
            {
                _idcode = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IDCode");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _avstock;

    public string AvailableStock
    {
        get
        {
            return _avstock;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _avstock)
            {
                _avstock = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AvailableStock");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _blstock;

    public string BlockedStock
    {
        get
        {
            return _blstock;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _blstock)
            {
                _blstock = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("BlockedStock");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _totstock;

    public string TotalStock
    {
        get
        {
            return _totstock;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _totstock)
            {
                _totstock = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalStock");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _detinf;

    public string DetailedInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _detinf;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _detinf)
            {
                _detinf = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DetailedInfo");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _uom;

    public string UOM
    {
        get
        {
            return _uom;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _uom)
            {
                _uom = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UOM");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _wareh;

    public string WarehouseName
    {
        get
        {
            return _wareh;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _wareh)
            {
                _wareh = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("WarehouseName");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and add a binding of the ItemsSource to the correct viewmodel

```
private void StockItemOverview_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.StockItemList;

        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls mark any one of the above responses as answer if that helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: I had to wait a day before I could accept my own question, sorry!
(1 hour now)